# Laravel / lumen incompatible foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have two tables, one is `profiles`. Below is how the migration file for `profiles` looks like

```
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create(
        'profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique()->notNullable();
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->integer('category')->unsigned();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('category')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

`profiles` has a foreign key `id` on its local `category field`. The migration file for `categories` table looks like so

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('abbrv');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The problem is when i try to add data to the profiles table, i get below error

> `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a  foreign key constraint fails (`authdb`.`profiles`, CONSTRAINT`profiles_category_foreign`FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES`categories`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert  into`profiles`(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`category`,`password`,`updated_at`,`created_at`) values (Salim, jon.doe@gmail.com, 2557000000, 2, $2y$10$OgpgD61e9Ihob4oE1LoRZuMkMY/1u6yLzxPKvs36TAQtQzSfqShMS, 2020-04-19 13:34:20, 2020-04- 19 13:34:20))`

How do i define the foreign key constraint so it doesn't throw constraint errors ?

Comment: It should be `category_id` not `category`

Comment: @A.ANoman how can it be category_id while there is no column named `category_id` ? Your solution won't work